# How to import and cut n images in 6 parts hopefully proportional to the written and export them to a directory?

Tags: graphics, export, image-processing, image, code-request

I tried to get it well formatted but I won it

I hope the question is understood
I'm using the google form which allows you to do multiple choice tests, if they were language no problem, the problem they are math exercises and the only way they look decent is by inserting pictures both in the problem header with in the alternatives, but cutting each picture of each problem means 6 cuts and if they are 30 questions is a long time.
The idea is to have "x" amount of images in a directory and that mathematician import them one by one P01.png,P02.png.... and identify the black color of the writing and cut the image in 6 parts if you can of the same size of the writing and name them of the form p01. png, p01_a.png,p01_b.png,p01_c.png ,p01_d.png,p01_e.png,p02.png, p02_a.png,p02_b.png,p02_c.png ,p02_d.png,p02_e.png....... and save them in a subdirectory "y" inside "x
Someone could help me please

[image: Image from P01.png]
Image from P01.png

[image: Image from p01.png]
Image from p01.png

[image: Image from p01_a.png]
Image from p01_a.png

[image: Image from p01_b.png]
Image from p01_b.png

[image: Image from p01_c.png]
Image from p01_c.png]

[image: Image from p01_d.png]
Image from p01_d.png

[image: Image from p01_d.png]
Image from p01_e.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update 2**

This is a better implementation of the `parts` function that does not assume that the spacings are the same. It finds groups of rows in the image that are not composed of entirely white pixels and splits by those groups.

```
ClearAll@parts

parts[image_] := Module[{width, height, imageData},
  {width, height} = ImageDimensions@image;
  imageData = ColorConvert[image, "Grayscale"] // ImageData;

  imageData // 
  Position[#, ConstantArray[1., width]] & //       
  Flatten //
  Complement[Range[height], #] & //     
  Split[#, (#2 - #1 == 1 &)] & //
  Map[MinMax] //   
  Map[Take[imageData, #] & /* Image]]
```

The rest of the code in the update below is unchanged.

**Update**

To process a directory of images

```
importPath = "path to import directory";
exportPath = "path to export directory"; (* Must already exist *)

ClearAll[parts, exporter];

parts[image_] := ImagePartition[image, Scaled[{1, 1/6}]] // Flatten

exporter[baseName_, parts_] := 
 MapThread[
  Export[baseName <> "_" <> #1 <> ".png", #2] &, {{"a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"}, parts}]

importedImages = AssociationMap[Import, FileNames["*.png", importPath]];

importedImages // 
  KeyValueMap[exporter[FileNameJoin[{exportPath, FileBaseName@#1}], parts[#2]] &];
```

---

If the spacing between the text is the same then you can partition it

```
img = Import["~/Downloads/21ttc.png"];
parts = ImagePartition[img, Scaled[{1, 1/6}]] // Flatten
```

[image]

Each image in the list can be exported to a different file.

```
MapThread[Export["P01_" <> #1 <> ".png", #2] &, {{"a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"}, parts}]
```

Comment: thanks what you expose serves me because they are at the same space,you could modify the code to do it importing all the images from a directory "x" dothe process and then export them to a directory "y" , n this code, MapThread[Export["P01_" <> #1 <> ".png", #2] &, {{"a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"}, parts}] P01_should be increased successively.

Comment: @juanmuñoz A couple of questions so I can update the answer correctly. In directory `x` do all of the files have the `.png` extension? For the export filename, rather than `P` I suggest using <import_filename>_<alphabet> that way it is easy to associate an input file with its parts. Is that OK?

Comment: So for the example above, the export files would be 21ttc_a.png, 21ttc_b.png, etc.

Comment: @ Rohit Namjoshiin the directory "x" all the files have extension .pngse call P01.png ,P02.png ....... referring to the questions , as for the export to the directory "y" it would be important to differentiate the question from the alternatives, but what you do can be useful and any doubt I ask you , and thanks for your time

Comment: @juanmuñoz Updated the answer. Let me know if you run into issues.

Comment: @RohitNamjoshin    ,Thank you very much, I made a small adaptation to your code and it works perfectly. The problem I have now is that the questions and their alternatives are seen at equal distance at first glance, but when I cut the mathematics I realize that it is not so and I have to edit the original question. 
In the cutting process you could add a third directory in which the questions are exported before cutting them in such a way that mathematica draws a line where it is supposed to make the cuts in order to edit the question more easily (I don't know if it is understood)

Comment: @juanmuñoz Do you mean something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OnlJy.png)? The red lines show where the image will be partitioned.

Comment: @RohitNamjoshin,Yes, so it is easier to edit if there are problems

Comment: Here is the function I used to do that. Should be easy to modify the code to run it and export to wherever you want. Let me know if you have any problems doing that. `partsMarked[image_] := ImagePartition[image, Scaled[{1, 1/6}]] // ImageAssemble[#, Spacings -> 1, Background -> Red] &`

Comment: @RohitNamjoshin,I've tried to implement it in different ways but it doesn't do anything visible, let alone export it to a directory on the hard disk  :(

Comment: @juanmuñoz What exactly did you try? The `partsMarked` function takes an image and returns an image with red lines drawn at the partition boundaries. You will have to create another exporter function to export to wherever you want. Edit your original question and add the code you tried.

Comment: @RohitNamjoshin,I see I have misunderstood your suggestion, I have to do another code for the last question, I speak Spanish I use translator, the truth is I do not know how to do the code, I do not handle much with the functions of import and export, I thought it was a matter of interspersing the code you passed me somewhere in your original code, but it is not so.

Comment: @juanmuñoz Ha, I am sure your English is much better than my Spanish :-) I have a much better idea that will not require any editing in case the spacing is not uniform. I do not have time to work on it today, but I will tomorrow.

Comment: @RohitNamjoshin,thank you for your effort and dedication, your help is very grateful for me. I will be attentive to your idea.

Comment: @juanmuñoz Try the new implementation of the `parts` function.

Comment: @RohitNamjoshin,works quite well, with some details but they are the least,  https://postimg.cc/QVWcJLRk ,I want to thank you for your help, to insist I think it would be asking too much.

Comment: @juanmuñoz You are welcome and thank you for the accept. If there is some noise in the image you can try some of the image filtering functions shown [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/ImageFilteringAndNeighborhoodProcessing.html).